# Exclude certain words from text-transform capitalize

Tags: html, css

My `HTML` is

```
<span id="search">filter for customers</span>
```

And `SCRIPT` is

```
$('#search').css('text-transform','capitalize');
```

Which gives me the result as

```
<span id="search">Filter For Customers</span>
```

My query is how can I exclude the word 'for' from being capitalized. In such a way that the result must be

```
<span id="search">Filter for Customers</span>
```

Please note, that this is just an example, I have a list of words that must not be capitalized. I am looking for some dynamic solution that whenever those words are found by should not capitalized by `text-transform`.
Thanks.

Comment: Wrap each word that you want to be capitalized to different span and apply CSS via classes. Is there any more words that should not be capitalized? How script should know these words?

Comment: you should want `for` instead of `For` ???

Comment: @Dr.Strange, yes I want `for` instead of `For`.

Comment: so you code manually for that using `php or javascript` or you can write `text` in separate `div`

Comment: @Justinas, yes there may be more words to be excluded. I can provide array for that.

Comment: @Dr.Strange, I can give a `JS Array` for the excluded words, or if there is any other way, I can do it?

Comment: array of worlds that you want them first letter be low case??

Comment: @לבנימלכה, yes this is what I was thinking.

Comment: the world exist in diffrent sentences??

Comment: @לבנימלכה yes they exist in different sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to loop all your texts and check if it's lower-by-default. This method is slow for big texts

```js
String.prototype.ucFirst = function()
{
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substr(1);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  var lowerWords = [
      'for', 'to'
  ];
  
  $('.uc-first').each(function () {
    var words = $(this).text().split(' ');
      pattern = /([^a-z0-9]*)(\w+)([^\w]*)/i
    
    $.each(words, function (i, value) {
      mathches = pattern.exec(value);
      if (lowerWords.indexOf(mathches[2]) == -1) {
        words[i] = mathches[1]+mathches[2].ucFirst()+mathches[3];
      }
    });
    
    $(this).text(words.join(' '));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="uc-first">some text for SO Community to investigate</span><br/>
<span class="uc-first">test ;for. additional symbols;</span><br/>
<span class="uc-first">filter for customers</span>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `id` to a `class` and wrap each word you want capitalised in the span with the `.search` class

**HTML**:

```
<span class="search">filter</span> for <span class="search">customers</span>
```

JS:

```
$('.search').css('text-transform','capitalize');
```

**Output**:

```
Filter for Customers
```

Comment: I am looking for some dynamic solution rather than manually adding `<span>` to the excluded words.